# Connect pyodbc in a docker container to a database outside the container

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, pyodbc

I have a PostgreSQL database running on a Windows machine. I'm attempting to connect from a python program running in a docker container to this database using `pyodbc`. Both database and docker container are running on the same machine.

I use docker compose to define the container:

```
version: "3.0"
services:

  web:
    image: img-python
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
      - "5432:5432"
    working_dir: /code
    entrypoint:
      - /pyenv/bin/gunicorn
    command:
      - -b 0.0.0.0:5000
      - --reload
      - app.frontend.app:app
```

I try to connect like so:

```
   conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={PostgreSQL ANSI};Server=localhost;Port=5432;
   Database=pydb_0001;UserName=uuuu;Password=pppp;String Types=Unicode')
```

> pyodbc.OperationalError: ('08001', '[08001] could not connect to
> server: Unknown error\n\tIs the server running on host "localhost"
> (127.0.0.1) and accepting\n\tTCP/IP connections on port 5432?\n (101)
> (SQLDriverConnect)')

How to fix the port mapping?

I tried with `network_mode: "host"` removing the ports and didn't work either.

Comment: On a Windows host using Docker Desktop, connect to `host.docker.internal`.  You do not need `ports:` (they are only for accepting connections _into_ the container) and I believe host networking doesn't work on any Docker Desktop setup.

Comment: Thanks David. Where do I put `host.docker.internal` in the pyodbc connection string?

Comment: As the `Server=` host name.

Comment: perfect, it worked